# jquery Datepicker date range validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a field like Born date. I have used jquery datepicker to show the calender so that user can select the date.Now I have a problem.

In the the Born date field there is a option to choose between which opens two date picker fields like

Born Date -- Between--------- ---From------- And --To----------

Now the problem is if the user selects a date in 'To field' which is less than 'From field' and press the submit button it gets submitted. I need to prevent it from submitting and display appropriate message so the user enters right date .

Please Help.

Here is the code that i am using

```
<input id="borndate"  class="dateISO" onchange="checkDate('borndate');">
</input>

<span id="span_borndate" style="display:none">
<input  id="borndate"  class="dateISO"  onchange="checkDate('borndate');">
</span>
```

This is the Java script i am using

```
function checkdate(fieldname) {

    var comparator = '#comp_' + fieldName;
    var compVal = $(comparator).val();
    Value = $('#' + fieldName).val();
    var fromDate = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate('mm-dd-yy', Value, null);
    Values = $('#' + fieldName + '-to').val();
    var toDate = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate('mm-dd-yy', Values, null);
    $('#span_' + fieldName).find('.error').remove();
    if (compVal == "Between") {
        if (toDate < fromDate) {
            $('#span_' + fieldName).append("<label class='rangeError' generated='false'>Start date should come before end date</label>");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And this is the function which is called again while submitting

```
function validateforms() {
    var valid = true;
    $('//classnamefor table rows which includes the date td').each(function (index) {
        fieldName = $(this).attr("name");
        if ($('#' + fieldName).hasClass('dateISO')) {
            valid = checkDate(fieldName);
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: can we get your markup and code you are trying?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max

Comment: i have already used it but the problem arises when user types the date himself in the datepicker field and i canoot keep it as read only

Comment: Please sort out the code formatting above - it's very difficult to read.

Comment: consider accepting/adding/editing the answer as your issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range

and make the textboxes readonly='true'

```
<input type="text" id="from" name="from_date" value="" readonly="true"/>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to_date" value="" readonly="true"/>
```

Comment: I have tried it mrsrinivas but what if user manulalay types a date which is less than from date there arise a problem of validation and i am facing it

Comment: Ok I have been able to solve the problem my self i had just to add this ocde in the function validateform  if(!checkDate(fieldName)){
                              valid = checkDate(fieldName)
                        }